# Zend_Captcha_Image stuck with font include path

Tags: zend-framework

```
$captcha = new Zend_Captcha_Image(array(
    'font' => BASE_PATH .'/fonts/Average-Regular.ttf'
));
$captchaId = $captcha->generate();
```

in index.php

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('BASE_PATH')
    || define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

error:

> Warning: imagepng(): Unable to open
>   './images/captcha/564749fc943b090f6d38233071ae1538.png' for writing:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/workbench/zend/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php on line
>   563

Comment: what is the directory path in which you have stored the font?

Comment: it's resides in root folder '/fonts/Average-Regular.ttf'

Comment: do you have another constant by name `APPLICATION_PATH` defined or you are using `BASE_PATH` instead of `APPLICATION_PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
$captcha = new Zend_Captcha_Image(array(
    'font' => BASE_PATH .'fonts/Average-Regular.ttf',
    'imgDir'=> //path to captcha image directory,
    'imgUrl'=> '/captcha-image/',
));
$captchaId = $captcha->generate();
```

you need to define the image directory in which you will be storing the captcha images.

for more information check out the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.captcha.adapters.html#zend.captcha.adapters.image

Answer (score 0):

For your font, '.' will point your Zend directory which holds your module directory.So for example, if you create a new directory like this ZendSkeletonApplication-master/data/fonts and put your font file like ZendSkeletonApplication-master/data/fonts/aril.ttf then you can initiate your captcha like the following:

```
$captcha = new Zend_Captcha_Image(array(
    'font' => './data/fonts/arial.ttf',
    'imgDir'=> 'your nominated directory',
    'imgUrl'=> 'same like above from url',
));
$captchaId = $captcha->generate();
```

But you can always define a constant in your index page which points to your chosen directory and use it.